# How to programmatically provide destination file path for printer added to the FILE port?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing, virtual

Using [AddPrinter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I have added a printer configuring it to the port "FILE".

Now whenever I choose this printer when printing, it opens a file browser asking for a path to save the document file (like the following).

[image]

I want to provide this path programmatically, like hard coding the path so that I won't get this pop up on selecting that particular printer for printing.

How can I achieve this? Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AddPort winapi function. add a new local
port and use the path to the file as the port name. Attach to printer. Printout your document. Enjoy it. Disadvantage: new job will overwrite the previous.

Comment: Though AddPort function did not help me as it simply opens the Add port wizard, but it paved the path. Found this XcvData function to add a port without a dialog box and giving the file path as port name did what I want.